# Can't connect to ASP.NET website from mobile phone

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, mobile-browser

I'm trying to access an asp.net MVC application from a mobile phone but I'm getting a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error from the chrome browser.

I have tried disabling the Firewall to see if this helps out but its not working as planned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use wi-fi from your phone when got this error?

Comment: Yes, my phone is connect via WIFI and im trying to reach one of my servers.

Comment: where is the mvc application hosted?

Comment: On a server on my network. Using IIS 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Since you use wi-fi it could be a DNS problem. Check if the wi-fi in the phone isn't set to the static IP address - it should be dynamic (DHCP). You can edit these settings in `Show advanced options` on your phone.

Comment: Correct. I'm running on DHCP

Comment: @Miguel That's strange, please try to clear DNS cache (a potential source of this issue) for you browser. On desktop you should type in address bar `chrome://net-internals/#dns` to clear the cache, you could try this trick on your mobile browser if you use chrome.

Comment: still getting the same issue. @user2771704